# Change default Url when start ASP.NET Core Razor pages web app

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

When run web, it running with url `http://localhost:5000/`.

How can I change that url to `http://localhost:5000/ABC` when starting web and also it will redirect to `Index.cshtml` in `ABC` folder (not `Pages` folder).

I try change it in `Program.cs` like this:

```
razorPage = builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/ABC/Index", "");
            })
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change `AddPageRoute` as follows , also change default pages directory as well :

```cs
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
   options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/index", "/abc/index");

}).AddRazorPagesOptions(opt => opt.RootDirectory = "/ABC");
```

and if you want change default home page route you can add end point as follows :

```cs
app.MapGet("/", context =>
{
   context.Response.Redirect("/abc/index");
   return Task.CompletedTask;
});

app.MapRazorPages();
```

Comment: @ Mohammad Aghazadeh. Thanks for your solution, that problem is solved. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

There are configuration options provided by a project's launch profiles. See the Url and App URL fields in the screenshot below. To get to these, right click the project in visual studio and select 'Properties'. Then navigate to the debug list item.

[image: VS Screenshot]